# How to update parent nodes in new branch of adjacency list table using SQL Server 2016/17?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, temp-tables, adjacency-list, sql-server-2017

I have adjacency list table where I need to clone set of nodes and insert it to a new branch. Basically I want to clone set of nodes having the same structure of parent nodes in new branch. I use temp table where I have source and inserted nodes. I tried to join temp table by item and use CTE but I got wrong result.

I tested [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830195/use-sql-to-clone-a-tree-structure-represented-in-a-database) but it does not work if parent nodes are same for more than 1 item.

How to update parent nodes (excluding root node) in a correct way?

Is there way to update it without using of temp table?

### Table

```
|node|parent|item|  
| 1  | Null | a  |  
| 2  | 1    | b  |    
| 3  | 1    | c  |
```

### Cloned nodes

```
|node|parent|item|  
| 4  | Null | a  |  
| 5  | 1    | b  |    
| 6  | 1    | c  |
```

### Temp table

```
|inserted_node|old_node|item|old_parent|  
| 4           | 1      | a  | Null     |  
| 5           | 2      | b  | 1        |  
| 6           | 3      | c  | 1        |
```

### Expected result

```
|node|parent|item|  
| 1  | Null | a  |  
| 2  | 1    | b  |    
| 3  | 1    | c  |    
| 4  | Null | a  |  
| 5  | 4    | b  |    
| 6  | 4    | c  |
```

### Wrong result

```
|node|parent|item|  
| 1  | Null | a  |  
| 2  | 1    | b  |    
| 3  | 1    | c  |  
| 4  | Null | a  |  
| 5  | 5    | b  |    
| 6  | 6    | c  |
```

### SQL Query

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
t.parent AS old_parent,
t2.node AS new_parent
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN @TempTable t2 ON t2.item = t.item
WHERE t.node IN (SELECT node FROM @TempTable ) AND t.parent IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET old_parent = new_parent
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the node column, is it an identity, or is it hard-coded? I guess my question is how do you know that the new cloned nodes should start with a node number of 4?

Comment: @Niels Berglund Yes node column is an identity. I used 'OUTPUT inserted.id INTO TempTable'. According to my app logic I need to insert new branch and only than update its parent nodes in new branch. I could solve it by joining temp table second time. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by joining temp table second time. Is there a better solution?

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT
t.parent AS old_parent,
t3.node AS new_parent
FROM Table t
LEFT JOIN @TempTable t2 ON t2.item = t.item
LEFT JOIN @TempTable t3 ON t2.parent = t3.old_node
WHERE t.node IN (SELECT node FROM @TempTable ) AND t2.parent IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET old_parent = new_parent
```

Comment: This only works if you are guaranteed that the child nodes, are always children of the parent (root) node. What I mean is if node 3 is child of node 2, then it would not work.

Comment: What if node 3 can be a child of node 2? Will Level(Depth) be useful in this case? What would you suggest to solve it?

Comment: Yes, level could be of use. I would suggest to not have node as identity in your table, that will make it easier to solve the problem. I have been working on some code here, but right now I don't have time to finish.